# Redirecting program output as input - pipe not working

Tags: java, c++, linux, io, bufferedreader

I am taking the output of one program (C++) as input for another (Java) using `BufferedReader`. When I run the Java program in my IDE and enter input in the console the program works as expected, however, when I try to pipe the input from the C++ program it no longer works with no errors given - no output is shown on the terminal window and no data is entered into the database. It is also worth noting that if I try running the `jar` in a terminal window and entering input the program does not work there either.

Reader Code:

```
BufferedReader input;
      try {
        input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String outputLine;
        String visionObjectName;
        String visionObjectTimestamp;
        String word = null;
        String timestamp = null;
        String whiteSpace = null;
        // Regex is used to check that the output is an object "name blankSpace timestamp" to avoid random output such as errors being entered.
        while ((outputLine = input.readLine()) != null) {
          System.out.println(outputLine);
          String regEx = "(^[a-zA-Z]*)(\\s+)((?:2|1)\\d{3}(?:-|\\/)(?:(?:0[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))(?:-|\\/)(?:(?:0[1-9])|(?:[1-2][0-9])|(?:3[0-1]))(?:T|\\s)(?:(?:[0-1][0-9])|(?:2[0-3])):(?:[0-5][0-9]):(?:[0-5][0-9]))";
          Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regEx, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
          Matcher m = p.matcher(outputLine);
          if (m.find()) {
            word = m.group(1);
            whiteSpace = m.group(2);
            timestamp = m.group(3);
          }
          visionObjectName = word + "" + whiteSpace;
          visionObjectTimestamp = timestamp;
          databasePopulation(visionObjectName, visionObjectTimestamp);
        }
```

I am using the Linux terminals pipe function to pass the information across.

Command:

```
./ORBMarkerDetection | java -jar ../layers/out/artifacts/layers_jar/layers.jar
```

EDIT:
For sake of thoroughness I've included the output code from the C++ program, would the method I'm using to print the timestamp be causing problems?

```
int timeFound() {
  time_t rawtime;
  struct tm * timeinfo;
  char buffer [80];
  time(&rawtime);
  timeinfo = localtime (&rawtime);
  strftime(buffer,80,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",timeinfo);
  puts(buffer);
  return 0;
}

void printFunction(String objectName) {
  if(nameArray[0] != objectName) {
    nameArray[0] = objectName;
    cout << nameArray[0] << " ";
    timeFound();
    cout << flush;
  }
}
```

As asked in comments, this is an example of the C++ output (from the line `Aug 17....` to `opengl support available` are only printed at program start and are not printed again.

```
Aug 17, 2015 11:57:03 AM com.layers.Main main
INFO: Logger Created.
Please enter activity number: 
1.1
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
init done 
opengl support available 
tap 2015-08-17 11:57:07
kitchenDoor 2015-08-17 12:57:07
fridge 2015-08-17 13:57:07
```

Also if I comment out the line beginning to the end of the scope:

```
String regEx...
...
}
```

The Java program outputs as expected to the terminal but I've had to comment out the database upload to test this so I cannot verify if the upload works.

Comment: Shouldn't you just handle the input as `main` method's parameters instead of a `System.in` stream?

Comment: The input will be continuous, not just at system start up.

Comment: There is no output given on the terminal screen with no data entered into the database.

Comment: Are you sure your other program is writing on the standard output and not the standard error stream?

Comment: The C++ is outputting using `cout`, is there a way to verify the main class in the jar file? The timestamp at creation is correct and I only have one class file named `main` within the code.

Comment: In order to use `-jar` the jars manifest needs to specify the main class (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html). Alternatively you can test with `./ORBMarkerDetection | java -cp ../layers/out/artifacts/layers_jar/layers.jar <main-class>`

Comment: I've tried running the command specifying `Main` as the main class but it still did not work as expected.

Comment: I've also included the C++ output in the original question.

Comment: See my original post, I've also added additional information when commenting out the regex code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing this by removing the defauls jar configuration and re-adding it, instructions below for anyone else using IntelliJ IDEA.

```
File -> Project Structure -> Artifacts
```

Then remove the jar settings using the small `minus` button and re-add using the `plus` symbol.

```
JAR -> From modules with dependencies -> OK
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the your program is blocked in something unrelated to the pipe. Most likely the database. The IDE could be setting a classpath and/or VM options that differ from what you enter at the terminal.

Get the exact command line being run by the IDE, if you don't know how to do this with your IDE you can do it with jps and /proc//cmdline.

eg. if I run jps while I am running my program in the IDE, I see:

13923 Jps
11333 MyJFrame
15006 Main

I know my main class is MyJFrame so I know my PID must be 11333.

If I  run cat /proc/11333/cmdline, I get:

```
/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_25/bin/java-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8-classpath/home/shackle/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication31/build/classesjavaapplication31.MyJFrame
```

It is missing the spaces between arguments but it is fairly obvious where they would go. Run that command after carefully inserting the spaces on the terminal.

Also, it would be a good idea to see exactly which line is executing when you run the jar and it produces no output. Run the original command, use jps to get the pid, use jstack  on that pid to get all the stack frames including the line it is blocked on.